# Pythononly pings 1 out of 2 IP's (Subprocess)

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, ping

I am trying to make a PY 2.7.x code there should ping a couple of addresses.
I have a list there contains two IP add. but it is only the last one there is being pinged ?

```
import subprocess

ip = ["10.0.2.5", "8.8.8.8"]
for i in range(len(ip)):
    ping_process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1'] + ip, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = ping_process.stdout.read()
    print stdout
```

Comment: In the popen call it should be ip[i]

Comment: I've tried that too and i get the following error :   File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    ping_process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1'] + ip[i],
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: I gave an answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your trying to add a string to a list this doesn't work.

```
>>> ["23123"] + "4234"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

You need to use .append() to add a element, but in this case just have the element in the list when you create it.

The issue might have never been encountered with better variable names consider the following.

```
import subprocess

list_of_ips = ["10.0.2.5", "8.8.8.8"]
for ip in list_of_ips:
    ping_process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = ping_process.stdout.read()
    print stdout
```

Comment: Thanks! the whole subprocess is more compley than I thougt! (First python code ever)